# How do I structure SPF Records?

Tags: spf

We send emails both through Google Apps, and also through Klaviyo - which is a tool a bit like mailchimp.

I'm keen to set an SPF record to make sure they're being authenticated correctly.

I asked my host to do it and they set two records as:

```
v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all
v=spf1 include:send.benefacto.org ~all
```

According to this https://support.google.com/a/answer/4568483?hl=en when you have multiple SPF records they all need to be wrapped into one e.g.

```
v=spf1 include:send.benefacto.org include:_spf.google.com ~all
```

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use `~all`, instead use `-all`. If you care about authentication, you might as well make it fail, if its bad.

Also I see that you're following Klaviyo's documentation, but I just want to clarify something, does your email go out with the return-path of @send.benefacto.org? This is referred to as the RFC5321.MailFrom.  This is what's used to test your SPF record. If it does you're good.

And your SPF record for send.benefacto.org should simply be.

```
v=spf1 include:send.benefacto.org -all
```

You don't need to include the google spf, because google doesn't use "send.benefacto.org" as it's RFC5321.MailFrom

Now for Google you need to fix it. Because you have 2 SPF records located here: [Your Benefacto.org SPF Records](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/dnstools/spf/benefacto.org/)

You don't need to combine it, you just need to remove this entry.

```
v=spf1 include:send.benefacto.org ~all
```

Which will leave you with just:

```
v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all
```

Since Klaviyo and Gmail send with different RFC5321.MailFrom - You don't have to combine them (I'm trying to drive this point home, you can it doesn't really hurt - just creates uneccassary lookups for the ESP)

You should also double check to make sure your SPF records actually validate correctly from both mailing sources by sending an email to **"mailtest@unlocktheinbox.com"**

You should also look into setting up DKIM and I think you'll be able to set up DMARC with relaxed alignments. But you'll need to be a little careful with DMARC and 3rd party senders and test accordingly.

Comment: Hello Henry, thank you for your considered and detailed reply and sorry for the sluggish response - I was on holiday.

I will check with Klaviyo what the return-path is. I think - from reading their tutorial - that for send.benefacto.org it is sendgrid.net.

Tutorial: https://www.klaviyo.com/docs/dns-records-for-email.

I'll look into setting up DKIM and DMARC - thanks for the tip!

Comment: Henry, I reviewed your response which was immensely helpful. Having done a bit of reading through Google and Klaviyo guidance, I've chosen this SPF record for 'benefacto.org'

v=spf1 include:send.benefacto.org include:_spf.google.com ~all

The Klaviyo tutorial requested SPF records for 'benefacto.org' as well as 'send.benefacto,org'. I chose '~all' over '-all' because Google said the latter could cause problems.
It is now throwing this error:

evaluating...
Results - PermError SPF Permanent Error: include has trivial recursion: include:send.benefacto.org

Can you advise why, please?
Thx! Linz

Comment: `v=spf1 include:send.benefacto.org include:_spf.google.com ~all` is a valid SPF Syntax Wise.  It's hard to tell what's happening without the header of your email. Can you pastebin the results from `mailtest@unlocktheinbox.com`

Comment: Hello Henry! Thanks for the help. I actually fixed it. I think it is because my host had put the wrong SPF record in for send.benefacto.org.

This mean't that when I put an SPF record for benefacto.org as 'send.benefacto.org' it went crazy.

I'm now struggling with DKIM. I've set it up for Klaviyo, but for some reason the Google ones aren't propagating.

Cheers for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to combine SPF directives into a single record on a domain.  The presence of multiple SPF records on a single domain is an error according to the spec.